# How to destruct all properties as local let in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

say i have a object :

```
const ob = { a : 1, b : 'hello world', c : 3, d : false, e : { zn : 'nested value' }};
```

I want a one liner, preferably using destructing to grab 5 new variables in local scope.

```
//do something with ob
//now i want to have 5 const/let defined in local scope
// such as, a =1, b = 'hello world', c = 3, d = false, e = { zn : 'nested value' }
```

EDIT1 : i have long key properties and there is 10 properties that i want to use all of them, directly without any dot, and i find writing 10 lengthy variable names boring..

Comment: is this just a thought exercise or do you genuinely need to use them as variables?

Comment: yes i genuinely want to use those, ob comes from importing some xyz utility file

Comment: Why not just create a new object from ob then? With shortened key names?

Comment: Right, but after that i just came curious as if such thing is possible ever.

Answer (score 3):

It is as simple as wrapping your desired identifiers in an object-style syntax

```
const {a, b, c, d, e} = {a: 1, b: 'hello world', c: 3, d: false, e: {zn: 'nested value'}};
a; // 1
b; // "hello world"
// etc
```

---

Note you can also go into arrays or go deeper into nests if needed;

```
const [{f: {g}}] = [{f: {g: 1}}];
f; // undefined
g; // 1
```

---

Further, you can rename identifiers during destructring

```
const {old: now} = {old: 1};
old; // undefined
now; // 1
```

Comment: i have long key name properties and there is 10 properties that i want to use directly without any dot.. writing 10 is bit boring...

Comment: You're going to have to write out the identifier names somewhere (don't use `with`, you'll never be able to debug it). If typing longhand is too much, I recommend you look into an IDE which supports tab completion. Code that someone else will understand in 5 years is more important than short identifier names.

Comment: i really appreciate the suggestions.. so +1, but i leave that not accepted.. so that in future some may attempt to bring magic. cheers

Comment: That magic will never happen. Magic like that is specifically why the `with` statement is deprecated. It slows down the language because the JS engine can't tell ahead of time where a variable name is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to shorten and assign them to a variable, one way is to use eval.

But then again, why do you need to create them as variables?

```js
const ob = { a : 1, b : 'hello world', c : 3, d : false, e : { zn : 'nested value' }};

var i = 0;
for (let key in ob)
{
  eval(`var index${i} = "${ob[key]}"`);
  i++;
}


console.log(index0);
console.log(index1);
console.log(index2);
```